# Apache htaccess issue on modRewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got an .htaccess file must to rewrite URLs for SEO friendly website,

So when i click on eg. an article ( eg www.example.com/article/this-is-an-artcle/ ) must to redirect me to index.php?article=this-is-an-article.

Same thing I must to do with the category page and admin page, so for completeness is something like this

```
www.ex.com/index.php?article=example-article -> www.ex.com/article/example-article   
www.ex.com/index.php?category=example -> www.ex.com/category/example
www.ex.com/index.php?page=admin -> www.ex.com/adm
```

Instead of this I must to hide the index.php file from the URL.

I'm doing this, but produce a **404 error**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?article=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^adm/?$ index.php?page=admin [QSA,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately If I open the apache.err.log can't see errors relating to the RewriteEngine, so i've tried to use `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6` in my .htaccess file, but didn't produce log, also tried to put a rewrite.log file in site folder, and make 777 permissions, no change, file still blank.

**EDIT:** Since this file work in another server ( cloud9 IDE ) and here not ( AWS Ubuntu 14.04 ) I'm assuming that I miss some configuration. How I can enable the LOG to see what's happen?

Comment: I get a not found error ( http://blog.andreaem.com/ )

Comment: Yes, all the URLs, check the link if you want

Comment: Got the same error, 404.

Comment: Sorry was a typo error. was correct in my htaccess file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

andreaem, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteRule ^article/([a-zA-Z-_]+)+$ index.php?article=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z-_]+)+$ index.php?category=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^adm$ index.php?page=admin [L]
```

Comment: Damn, no changes, the file I've posted in question is working in another server ( at cloud9.io ) but not here ( AWS Ubuntu 14.04 ) I think here I miss something, but can't understand what.

Comment: @andream If you tested the same .htaccses file at a different  server, and works…. I suggest you to verify the Apache’s httpd.conf file parameters: 
    <Directory />
            Options All
      AllowOverride All
</Directory>
Note: if you test on local serever, Apache Xammp or Maammp has a console where you can modify any the config files, also to see the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through a syntax checker perhaps

E.g. http://www.htaccesscheck.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I actually already tested it using this tool before submitting here, the result was: Syntax checks out ok!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting 404 error status becouse of the relative rewrite targets, add a slash before your traget paths ie :( **/index.php** )

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^article/([\w-]+)/?$ /index.php?article=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: No changes, got the same 404 error, It's possible that I missed some php plugin or configuration?